# How can I play local mp3 on flutter web?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I try a lot packages, but no one can play a mp3 file from local file...

users can chiose a file from systerm

```
_myFile = await FilePickerCross.importFromStorage(
      type: FileTypeCross.audio,  
);
```

then , how can i play it on flutter web page ?

usually crash:

```
Error: NotSupportedError: Failed to load because no supported source was found.
    at Object.createErrorWithStack (http://localhost:62567/dart_sdk.js:4352:12)
    at Object._rethrow (http://localhost:62567/dart_sdk.js:38191:16)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:62567/dart_sdk.js:38185:13)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:62567/dart_sdk.js:38017:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:62567/dart_sdk.js:38023:13)
    at http://localhost:62567/dart_sdk.js:33520:9
```

like this https://github.com/florent37/Flutter-AssetsAudioPlayer/issues/383

so can any way to play local mp3 file on flutter web?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `audioplayers` package.

**To play audio from local file :**

```
AudioPlayer audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();      
playLocal() async {
  int result = await audioPlayer.play(localPath, isLocal: true);
}
```

For a detailed info please take a look at package documentation:

https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers

Comment: @pskink I think this package should work https://pub.dev/packages/assets_audio_player

Comment: but this accualy show "Error: NotSupportedError: Failed to load because no supported source was found." (i see the localPath is "C:/fakepath/210107-121628165221_1.wav" using macos)

Comment: assets_audio_player can not play too. and i think any package would failed, cause this might be a flutter issuse

Comment: @capdev I think you should raise an issue on GitHub

Comment: this is because you simply cannot access any local file from the flutter web

Answer (score 0):

You can copy paste run full code below 
The following demo code has well tested on flutter web
you can use package https://pub.dev/packages/soundpool and call `_soundpool.loadAndPlayUint8List(_myFile.toUint8List());` 
code snippet

```
Soundpool _soundpool;

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  _soundpool = Soundpool();
  
...
FilePickerCross _myFile = await FilePickerCross.importFromStorage(
      type: FileTypeCross.audio,
    );

_soundpool.loadAndPlayUint8List(_myFile.toUint8List());
```

full code

```
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:file_picker_cross/file_picker_cross.dart';
import 'package:soundpool/soundpool.dart';

Soundpool _soundpool;

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  _soundpool = Soundpool();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() async {
    FilePickerCross _myFile = await FilePickerCross.importFromStorage(
      type: FileTypeCross.audio,
    );

    _soundpool.loadAndPlayUint8List(_myFile.toUint8List());

    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```